# unreasonable error while scraping yahoo finance

Tags: python

I'm going to scraping the daily k-value of some stocks at the website "yahoo finance".

The code is very simple and it seems nothing unusual, but it still appears error while compiling.
I don't realize the reasons.

My code is below

```py
import requests

import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://tw.screener.finance.yahoo.net/screener/basic.html'
r=requests.get(url)
obj=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
table=obj.find('div', {'class': 'result_table'}).find_all('span')[1].text
print(table)
```

**the compiling result is below:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python2\0228.py", line 11, in <module>
    table=obj.find('div', {'class': 'result_table'}).find_all('span')[2].text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: It's not finding the DIV.

Comment: There's no `<div class="result_table">` in the HTML for that page. It's added by JavaScript.